# Installing Team Foundation Server 2008: error TF220059

Tags: installation, team-foundation-server

Scenario:

- Windows 2003 with SP2 running as a guest in vmWare.
- 20gb HDD and 1GB RAM.
- SQL Express 2005 with Service Pack 3 as Named Instance.
- SQL 2005 is well configured; known working good; can login, no security problems, etc.
- installing from the 90 day trial disc: [VS2008TeamFoundationServerENU90DayTrialX1429244.iso](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/info.aspx?na=45&p=1&SrcDisplayLang=en&SrcCategoryId=&SrcFamilyId=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86&u=details.aspx%3ffamilyid%3dB0155166-B0A3-436E-AC95-37D7E39A440C%26displaylang%3den)

The problem occurs at the screen asking:

> Type the name of the server that hosts the Team Foundation Server database.

The wording seems to indicate that you'd have already installed a DB!

I soldiered on with gusto, typing in the server's DB instance:

> MyServer\SQLExpress

The official error description:

```
 Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation Server Setup

TF220059: An error occurred while the Setup program was querying the
installation settings for Team Foundation Server.
```

[MSDN Social has a good thread on TF220059](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/75755de5-8b1a-4b70-9559-f5e8d058ddbb), but none of those suggestions didn't work for me. Initially, I didn't have a service pack on my SQL Express. I have since upgraded to SP3 (+ rebooted), but that did not help.

The MSDN Social thread suggests for some people that installing SQL Reporting Services solves the problem. Some reported that it did NOT solve the TF220059 problem.

**Question**: Any suggestions on what needs to be configured/installed to solve the TF220059 problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Express is not supported for TFS 2008, you must use SQL 2005 or SQL 2008.  A full license of TFS comes with a limited use license of SQL Server Standard (basically limited to use only by the TFS application)

SQL Express is supported by TFS 2010, and in fact if you do a basic installation without SQL Express pre-installed it will install it for you.

Comment: +1 - after a few hours attempting to install TFS 2008 with SQL Server Express 2005, this saved the day, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've set up TFS a few weeks ago, and had a lot of trouble because nearly everything I tried was not supported.

I endet up not using Windows Server 2008, but 2003R2 instead.
Therefore I did use the older IIS 6 as well.
I did not use SQL Server 2008, but 2005SPx instead.
I did not use a localized version of Windows & SQL Server but the english one instead.
Do not install Sharepoint services myself, instead let TFS setup handle this.

Setup of TFS was a real PITA! I only got it to run properly using the recommended software versions (WS 2003, SQL 2005, all in english).
Whenever I installed it with some other version, either installation failed, or it just did not work, with some very weird error messages. Especially using non-english-Windows Server lead to strange behaviour after installation.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Express by default does not expose TCP/IP connectivity. Goto All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2005 > Configuration Tools > **SQL Server Configuration Manager**

For the SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration, look at the Protocols for SQLEXPRESS and enable TCP/IP if it is disabled.

Verify that all ports stated in the TFS installation guide are open at the database server for the app-tier server to make a connection to. [You may also want to ensure WMI ports are open for discovery](http://community.sgdotnet.org/groups/vsts/wiki/installation-problems-windows-2008.aspx).

UPDATE

After getting back to refer back to the installation guide, I do not think SQL Server Express is a supported edition for TFS. The supported editions are Standard or Enterprise edition. SSAS is needed.

Comment: Great suggestion about WMI. TCPIP is good. Can login remotely. SQL 2005 is well configured; known working good; can login, no security problems, etc.

Comment: Suggestion updated

Answer (score 0):

For those wishing to have TFS installation tips or a walkthrough, follow the instructions at Peter Stromquist's blog:

[Building a virtualized Team Foundation Server development environment](http://beyondthispoint.blogspot.com/2005/11/building-virtualized-team-foundation.html)

This has helped clear up a few points on requirements and laying the foundation for installing TFS in a virtual machine. Thanks Peter!